# Word for someone who thinks too highly of another

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives

What word would you call someone who thinks too highly of another person, Even though they may not be perfect?

Comment: Do you mean 'thinks too highly' or just 'thinks highly'? The first implies that this is not good, the second is neutral. And also should the second sentence refer to the other person - 'Even though the other person may not be perfect.'

Comment: Depends.  Is it me they think highly of?

Comment: nice person to know.

Comment: The close vote is not warranted.

Answer (score 1):

[**Idolator**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idolator):

> a person that admires intensely and often blindly one that is not usually a subject of worship

This follows from the word [idolize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idolize), where, for example:

> she blindly *idolized* her older sister, refusing to acknowledge her considerable faults

Answer (score 0):

[Worshipper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worshipper)
: to regard with great or extravagant respect, honor, or devotion a celebrity worshipped by her fans

There is also the idiom "He worships the ground she walks on"
: to admire/love someone very much He worships the ground she walks on.